# Position fixed images always 50px from right of screen

Tags: css, positioning

Im using semplicelabs to build my website. and im making some fixed social icons that need to be positioned about 50px from the right of the screen like so:

[image: what i want]

but to do things like this in semplicelabs i have to use custom code to position it and make it fixed. so this is what it looks like currently:

[image: what i have]

This is the code i have and i gave them these classes. Sould it be my top and left position messing it up?

```
    .icon {
  width: 24px;
  right: 0px;
}


.fixed-section {
  position: fixed !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

/* This makes our fixed elements clickable */
.fixed-section .column-content {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: It might be, because of the css of the parent element. What does the css for the parent look like?

Comment: please share your markup

Comment: If you are aligning it to the right, then remove the left completely. I think you'll need to have top to be at 50% of the screen. 
Create a JS fiddle or Codepen with the code and share.

Comment: can you put your code in codepen or sandbox and put here a link so people can help you easier? thanks

Comment: So i here is the webpage so you all can see: warrenbreedlove.com/home-page-test

Comment: I currently removed the left and added the top:50% but its not quite in the middle.

Comment: I know its kinda weird im new to using the site building things where you have to make the element then adjust it with custom css. so hopefully charing the link to the site will help

Comment: Its also not to the right as far as it needs to be. trying to get it to be to the right of the screen to kinda like up with the left padding of the nav bar

Comment: https://warrenbreedlove.com/home-page-test